# Pass variables while uploading a files

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a form with many fields, one of them is a file upload.

Into the form there is this field:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-2">ID Ordine</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" size="100" maxlength="100" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
         <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I created this file upload zone inside a div:

```
<div class="m-dropzone dropzone m-dropzone--primary" action="/file_upload_prodotto" id="m-dropzone-two" >
    <div class="m-dropzone__msg dz-message needsclick">
        <input type="file" name="file_ordine">
        <h3 class="m-dropzone__msg-title">Trascina o clicca su questa finestra per aggiungere i file.</h3>
    <span class="m-dropzone__msg-desc">Tieni premuto CTRL per selezionare piú file.</span>
</div>
```

and in flask I upload the files like:

```
@app.route('/file_upload_prodotto', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file_upload_prodotto():
data = request.form
print(data)
if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['file']
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'file_prodotti'), exist_ok=True)
    f.save(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'file_prodotti', secure_filename(f.filename)))
    print(f)
return 'file uploaded successfully'
```

I can upload the file without any problem.
My real problem is that I have to link this file to a particular id, I have this id in the form.
My idea was to get this id and then write a function to update the database of that particular id with the name of the file that I uploaded.
But I can't figure out how to get the id.
Can you guys help me?

Comment: You'll have to update your question and include the source of `id`. Are you adding it manually or is it from an object with a relationship to the photo?

Comment: @roy hi, the id is added manually by the user. I want to be able to link that id to the file updated.

Comment: Input tags should be nested inside a form tag, if not use a form attribute tag with a value similar to form id attribute. What's supposed to be your form action is inside a div `<div class="m-dropzone dropzone m-dropzone--primary" action="/file_upload_prodotto" id="m-dropzone-two" >`.

Answer (score 0):

So in your form you will need to note the id:

```
<div class="m-dropzone__msg dz-message needsclick">
    <input type="file" name="file_ordine">
    <input name="photo_id">
    ...
```

To access the photo id in your flask route:

```
...

photo_id = request.form['photo_id']
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply but it doesn't work, while I'm uploading the file, if I try to print data it gave me just `None`